# Trabalhando com Array e selecionando um indice especifico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nos meus estudos em JS eu tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<select name='options'>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>  

<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="date" />
```

Preciso que baseado no select ele mostre o input referente ao indice dele.

**Exemplo:** Se selecionei A, ele mostra o input 1, se selecionei B ele esconde o 1 e mostra o 2. E assim em diante. A idéia é que apareça apenas um elemento do tipo input na tela, e todos os outros estejam com `display: none;`

Porem não posso usar uma class extra para diferenciar. O que tive como idéia foi usar um array, e fazer um For, mas não tive evolução com isso.

Comment: não pode usar `id`?

Comment: não Marconi a idéia é realmente usar talvez um Sort e fazer o if`s para comparar se o val() corresponde ao input. É bem tosco o exemplo, por que a idéia é realmente usar o array e fazer correspondência de Indice.

Comment: Entendi que de acordo com o indice do primeiro selecionado selecione o segundo select?

Comment: Isso mesmo, algo como A = 1, B = 2 e etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a propriedade [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) como argumento da função [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) para selecionar o `<input>` pelo índice.

```js
$('[name=options]').bind('change', function(){
    $('.input').hide() // ocultar todos
      .eq(this.selectedIndex).show(); // selecionar pelo índice e exibir
}).trigger('change'); // forçar execução imediata
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='options'>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>  

<input class="input" type="text" value="A" />
<input class="input" type="text" value="B" />
<input class="input" type="text" value="C" />
```

Comment: +1 pelo selectedIndex, já vai me servir pra outras coisas. Vou editar minha resposta utilizando a propriedade.

Answer (score 1):

Então, veja se dessa maneira ajuda.

Acho que só deve ser melhorada a forma de verificar o índice, dessa maneira acho que fica muito manual, mas já é um caminho.

**EDITADO**: Usando o `selectedIndex` citado pelo @Sanção substitui o switch e ficou um código mais limpo.

```js
var listaInputs = $('input');
var listaOption = $('option');

$('select[name="options"]').change(function() {
  listaInputs.hide();
  $(listaInputs[this.selectedIndex]).show();
});

$('select[name="options"]').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='options'>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigão fiz um exemplo em jquery para você testar.

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/4cmpv6y2/)

Olhe que basicamente eu pego o valor do input, procuro o obj e dou show nele, bem simples.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.input').hide();
$("select[name='options']").val(-1);
$("select[name='options']").change(function(){
    $('.input').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
});
```

Veja e fale se deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```js
var input = $("input");
$('#opcoes').change(function() {
  var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
  input.hide();
  $(input[index]).show();
  input[index].value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='options' id="opcoes">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="text" />
<input class="input" type="date" />
```